# I need to exclude one profile from a validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

Lead Source a mandatory field and the validation rule on conversion  means it has to be completed. this is true for all our users with the exception of 1 user profile. How can I exclude them from this validation rule? All help very much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an exception for a profile in the validation rule with something like this:

```
ISPICKVAL(LeadSource,"")
&&
$User.ProfileId <> "exemptedProfileId"
```

Then of course replace exemptedProfileId with the Id of your profile that is exempt from the validation rule.

Keep in mind that it is generally not a great idea to hard code Ids in formulas, but in this case, I can't think of another way to make this happen for your use case, since you are indeed targeting a specific metadata record

UPDATE 10/18/23: Forgot that LeadSource is a picklist field. The updated formula will work for picklist fields.

Comment: or `$Profile.Name <> 'exemptProfileName'` or `$User.Profile.Name <> 'exemptProfileName'`

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I try this I get an error saying 'Field LeadSource is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten that is a picklist field. I've updated my answer to show the correct formula. You can find documentation for these restrictions here:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&type=5

And yes, @cropredy is right, you can also use the name of the profile. In my opinion though, you are less likely to change to a new exempt profile than change the profile name, so I think using the profile Id may be a bit more reliable long term. Depends on your situation

Comment: @Miguel Thanks for all your help but I must be doing something wrong. Here is the validation rule - $Setup.Process_Dectivation__c.Disable_Validation_Rules_c=FALSE, &&, IsConverted, &&, (ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c,""), [[ ISPICKVAL(LeadSource,"") && $Profile.Name <> 'pgbusdevteam', [[ ISBLANK(Area_of_Interest__c) [[ (ISPICKVAL(Sector__c,"") && NOT(ISPICKVAL(Industry,"Charity")))). I have added in the Profile Name line, is this in the wrong place.

Comment: Hi Pam,
Sorry I hadn't responded. Did you figure this out already? If not, I could help separately through a Google Meet call or something like that for 10-15 min if useful. We can discuss that separately if it would be useful

Comment: @MiguelDiaz many thanks for your response and all your help, this has now been resolved